# Check sum in list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to also check the sum of the digits in the list in the same comprehension and make another except if the sum exceeds 50?

```
        k = input("input digits separated by spaces:")
        try:
            [int(i) for i in k.split()]
        except ValueError:
            print("input only digits")
```

The main thing is not to structure it with two except blocks, but to keep it as simple as possible make sure that the sum of the list is not more than 50.

Comment: What's the problem with writing one or two lines of code more?

Comment: Not sure what you meant , sum([int(i) for i in k.split()]) should sum them up

Comment: Uhm, how 'make another'? You can run any function on i in your example... You only want to run the comprehension until the sum of i's is 50?

Comment: I want k to concist only of digits and the sum of the digits in k.split() not to exceed 50.

Comment: In "digits" do you mean single digits (0-9) or simply any number? Because your current test will accept "1 10 15 23" as well...

Comment: What do you actually care about, the list or the sum? What value do you want to walk away with when you're successful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`assert sum([int(i) for i in k.split()]) <= 50` and add an `except 
AssertionError` would do the trick:

```
k = input("input digits separated by spaces: ")
try:
    assert sum([int(i) for i in k.split()]) <= 50
except ValueError:
    print "input only digits"
except AssertionError:
    print "Sum of digits is grater than 50"
```

Though I must say that I find this a rather poor design...

Comment: Do you have any ideeas how to make a better design?

Comment: It's quite simple: More lines of code are not necessarily bad.
I'm generally against overly complicated one-liners. Sometimes writing several lines of code for readability is better. Try iterating over the list summing it along with the testing of the elements in the list checking the 2 conditions in the body of the loop. I think you'll find the code easier to understand and manage, and at the same time spare yourself the over-use of exceptions. Try reading about `str.isdigit`.

Comment: **Never use `assert` for core application logic, and *especially* not for validating user input.** `assert` is *not* guaranteed to run, and in practice will not run in O or OO mode. Only use assert for testing.

Comment: @Mike He asked for a solution within the same comprehension, I gave him one. I did say it was a poor design. I'd never actually recommend the use of this kind of statement.

Comment: @immortal, This solution *doesn't work*, and for reasons you don't mention at that. It's also no more "within" the same comprehension as an if statement would be. It certainly doesn't actually *help* the original poster, which should always be a top goal.

Comment: @Sergei, To determine the optimal design, you should tell us more broadly what you're doing here. What are you doing with the data if it's valid and with it in each way it may be invalid? Without knowing what you want to end up with, it's impossible to determine the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
    k = input("Input integers separated by spaces:")
    try:
        the_list = [int(i) for i in k.split()]
        if sum(the_list) > 50:
            raise ValueError("The user's numbers' summation is too large.")
    except ValueError:
        print("Input only integers separated by spaces with sum not greater than 50.")
```